# Cannot find template with ID

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to use Knockout.js to merge an HTML view on an HTML document with an HTML code that is stored in a database table. Although it seems the code from the database is properly appended to the DOM, knockout says it can't find that ID.

My viewmodel has the following properties:

```
var viewModel = {
    Index: ko.observable(),
    Right: ko.observable(),
    Process: ko.observable(),
    Visual: ko.observable(),
    Data: ko.observable(),
    TemplateID: ko.observable(),
    FormID: ko.observable()
};
```

The visual is the object that has a property called "Control" which is a section of HTML code. Let's say, for simplicity, the code I download from my database is:

```
<form id="FormID">
     <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />
     <input type="text" id="Description" name="Description" />
</form>
```

My HTML view on the HTML document looks like this:

```
<div class="content" id="content" data-bind="with: chosenProcess">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <img class="search" title="Search" data-bind="visible: Rights.AllowRead" />
        <img class="add" title="Add" data-bind="visible: Rights.AllowCreate, 
            click: $root.loadControl" />
        <img class="save" title="Save" data-bind="visible: Rights.AllowUpdate, 
            click: $root.commitProcess" />
        <img class="close" title="Close" data-bind="click: $root.stopProcess" />
        <img class="delete" title="Delete" data-bind="visible: Rights.AllowDelete, 
            click: $root.stopProcess" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: TemplateID, data: Data }"></div>
</div>
```

The goal is to set chosenProcess and this will create the following HTML:

```
<div class="content" id="content" data-bind="with: chosenProcess">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <img class="save" title="Save" data-bind="visible: Rights.AllowUpdate, 
            click: $root.commitProcess" />
        <img class="close" title="Close" data-bind="click: $root.stopProcess" />
    </div>
    <form id="frmPOST-1-1-1">
        <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" />
        <input type="text" id="Description" name="Description" />
    </form>
</div>
```

After seeing the example on the documentation (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) I tried wrapping Visual.Control around a  tag, attaching it to the "content" element but knockout can't find it. I can find it using document.getElementByID, though.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

P.S.: Before any negative comments, I just started using knockout last week...

Comment: It doesn't look like you've defined a template here. Typically, this would be a script tag with the template name specified in the ID field. `<script type="text/html" id="myFancyTemplate"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to create a external template source

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/10/ko-13-preview-part-3-template-sources.html

edit:

Here is a example on how to implement a template source

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox/blob/master/src/knockout.combobox.js#L356

If you want to make it the default template source for KO you can do

```
ko.setTemplateEngine(stringTemplateEngine);
```

Also, have a look at this .NET Template Store that I have made

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.TemplateStore/wiki

Comment: Yes, this looks the closest to what I'm trying to achieve, but damn, am I having issues with this. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: You can look at this library I have written, it shows how to use the source template https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox/blob/master/src/knockout.combobox.js#L356

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you haven't defined a knockout template. That said, for what you're trying to accomplish, you don't need to use a template binding. You can use knockout's HTML binding to render the HTML content that you've fetched.

```
<div data-bind="html: Data"></div>
```

... assuming that Data is the name of the field that you've retrieved from the database.

Here's a quick fiddle to demonstrate the HTML binding:

http://jsfiddle.net/krainey/6sFVK/3/

If you're still having problems after that:

1. Verify that the data in your view model matches your expectations
2. Verify that you're calling applybindings for your viewmodel

You may find it useful to go through the knockout.js tutorials -- they cover the basics very well.

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/